# WiX: Why does the InstallDir dialog not accept input after I switch to Japanese characters?

Tags: windows-7, wix, windows-installer, ime, burn

I'm building a bilingual application installer with **Windows Installer XML** that uses a **Burn** bootstrapper to integrate MSIs for Windows XP, Windows 7 32 bit and Windows 7 64 bit into a single installer.

While I'm using the Burn UI for the opening dialog, internal MSI's dialogs handle install directory and shortcut options. I have a slightly customized version of the WiX InstallDirDlg.wxs where the user can change the installation directory.

Changing the directory works correctly when using English characters, in all three target OSs.

However, in both architecture versions of Windows 7, if you switch to Japanese character input when the focus is in the text field of that install directory dialog, the text field stops receiving data. The focus cursor continues to blink and you can select parts of the previously specified path, but typing doesn't replace anything. Other controls also still work, allowing you to go forward or back, or browse for a location, but you can't type anything in the browse-dialog text field either.

This persists until you close and reopen the installer.

The behavior does remind me of the times the Japanese IME decides to display *tentative* characters (i.e. hiragana before you specify which kanji it should convert to) in the corner of the screen instead of on the line you're typing, but usually the characters appear in the right place if you press the enter key after typing.
However, nothing gets displayed in the non-responding text fields; after a couple of presses the text field loses focus and the **Next**-button handles the enter keypress.

Is this a bug in WiX?

Or maybe a bug in the Windows 7 implementation of the Japanese IME?

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

**Update:**
On further testing I've discovered that if you have another keyboard locale installed when you switch from the Japanese IME the entered text appears in the text field. Until then, the Japanese IME remains unresponsive. Most Japanese users probably won't have other locales installed, so unfortunately this doesn't fix my issue.

I've also tried the installer on a Windows Vista machine, where it the text field works correctly with Japanese. I'm gravitating towards this being an issue with the IME, but I'm not sure if some WiX-coded installer behavior can instigate such a bug.

Comment: Does it maybe have something to do with the `Codepage`-attribute of the `Product`-element in WiX? What if you set the correct codepage for Japanese there?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've been trying the default values of  Codepage="932" and Language="1041" as well as others or not specifying any codepage settings, but they don't seem to have an effect.

I have discovered, however, that this behavior does not occur when the MSI installer is run on its own; only when part of a burn-bootstrapper. 

Might this behavior have something to do with how Burn invokes the internal MSI's GUI and the codepage settings of the burn engine? 
I couldn't find any way to set the codepage in the bootstrapper source files.

Comment: On a different note, I wrote in the post that the Next button handles the enter keypress if you press it a few times. It seems that 2 keypresses are always enough, which makes it seem like the Japanese IME is receiving input somewhere, but the parsed characters are simply not being committed to the folder path entry field. Usually you would press Enter once to commit the input, and the next Enter-press will be handled by the button with the focus.